# Collection of maximum disjoint sets

Tags: algorithm

Given a collection of a set of 3 numbers, find the maximum disjoint sets. For example, let C = {(3,4,5), (4,5,6), (1,2,3), (6,9,10), (7,8,9)}. This input should return 3, since the maximum disjoint sets are {(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)}. How can I write a program that will output the collection of maximum disjoint sets?

I've thought about starting off by selecting all 5 sets. Then, look at each set and see if removing that element will affect the rest of the sets. If we take away (3,4,5), it will allow us to keep (4,5,6) and (1,2,3). Thus, its net benefit is +1. We should remove it from our final list. Then, if we take away (4,5,6), it will allow us to keep (6,9,10). The net benefit is 0, so don't remove it. Removing (1,2,3) will affect nothing. Don't remove it. Removing (6,9,10) will allow us to keep (7,8,9). Not sure if that makes any sense but let me know what you think!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is a place for asking specific programming questions. A better question would include your attempt at a coded solution with specific parts that you have questions with.  Your question is very broad. Please try to narrow it down.  Take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Maximum disjoint sets - does it mean cover most elements, or maximum absolute number of such sets?

Comment: Are those sets always made from 3 sequential numbers? By contrast, should one expect a 3-number set like `{2,3,5}`?

Comment: @amit it means the second -- maximum number of such sets

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi they are not consecutive!

Comment: If we had sets (1,4,7) and (2,5,8), would the answer be 2 (my interpretation) or 1 (what I believe is Adrian's interpretation)?

Answer (score 1):

If the three numbers are always consecutive, then this has an easy dynamic programming solution (compute the maximum sets that can be placed using numbers 1..i using a recursive formula).

However, if this constraint is not always true, then this problem is NP hard.
It is NP hard is because it could be used to solve the NP-complete [3-dimensional matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching).

For example, suppose we are matching elements in X,Y,Z.  We can construct sets for each allowed match using numbers 1..|X| in the first position, |X|+1..|X|+|Y| in the second position and |X|+|Y|..|X|+|Y|+|Z| in the third position.  Once we have constructed these sets we can then solve the 3 dimensional matching problem using an algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you walk me through the 3-dimensional matching problem? What would X,Y,Z be in my case?

Comment: Nope, it's not NP-hard. It's N log(N) with a [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_disjoint_set#1-dimensional_intervals:_exact_polynomial_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Greedy will do. Note that the triplets are actually intervals, the mid number does not matter, only the start/end ones do (i.e. in `[start, whatever, end]` ignore `whatever`

The [O(N log(N)) greedy solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_disjoint_set#1-dimensional_intervals:_exact_polynomial_algorithm)

1. sort the intervals using a relation order which:

   - places the ones with higher ends towards the end (that is "[start<sub>i</sub>, end<sub>i</sub>] < [start<sub>j</sub>, end<sub>j</sub>]" iff "end<sub>i</sub> < end<sub>j</sub>"
   - at equal ends, the longer ones are higher (that is "[start<sub>i</sub>, end] < [start<sub>j</sub>]" iff "start<sub>j</sub> < start<sub>i</sub>" )
2. take a stack and push the last segment in
3. scan the sorted intervals downwards (the `k` index is current)

   - If the "start<sub>k</sub>" is higher than "start<sub>stack-top</sub>" (i.e. the curr interval lets more room in front of it), pop the top of the stack and push the current one.
   - If "start<sub>stack-top</sub>" > "end<sub>k</sub>" - the current one does not overlap with top of stack - simply push the current interval in the stack (is part of the solution).
   - otherwise, ignore the current interval (overlaps with the best solution we have so far; being greedy we don't want to lose it)

At the end, you will have the maximum count of the non-overlapping segments in to the stack, with the left-most on top - that is a space complexity of O(N).
If you need only to count them, note that only the top of stack is involved in comparison, so you only need to remember the top of the stack (each time you would pop/push replace the 'top-of-stack' with the current one and let the `count` unchanged; each time you only push replace the 'top-of-stack' and increment the count). So the space complexity for counting only is O(1).

---

your example:

1. after the sorting step, you have your intervals as {(1,2,3), (3,4,5), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (6,9,10)}
2. top of stack (6,9,10) - count 1. All the steps below are the unrolling of the cycle.
3. taking (7,8,9) - more conservative start, evict top of stack (out with the old) push the current (in with the new) - top of stack (7,8,9), count=1.
4. (4,5,6) - ends sooner than top of stack starts, collect it - top of stack (4,5,6), count=2;
5. (3,4,5) - smaller start but overlaps with top of stack. Be greedy - ignore/discard. Top of stack (4,5,6), count=2;
6. (1,2,3) - ends sooner than top of stack starts, collect it - top of stack (1,2,3), count=3;

End of downward cycle, the stack top-to-bottom reads: {(1,2,3}, (4,5,6), (7,8,9)} with a count of 3.

---

C++ (**not tested**)

```
struct interval { int s; int e; }

struct comparator {
  bool operator(const interval& i1, const interval& i2) const {
    int i=i1.e-i2.e; // higher ends placed last
    if(0==i) { // higher length/lower starts will be higher
      i=i2.s-i1.s;
    }
    return i<0;
  }
}

int count_intervals(std::vector<interval>& sets) {
  if(sets.empty()) return 0;

  comparator comp;
  std::sort(sets.begin(), sets.end(), comp);

  /* if you need the solution as well, use a stack */
  // std::stack<std::vector> solution;
  interval& stack_top=sets[sets.size()-1]; // solution.push(stack_top);
  int count=1; // we have at least one in the stack
  for(int i=sets.size()-2; i>=0; i--) {
    interval& curr=sets[i];
    if(curr.s > stack_top) { // a better one, lets more room in front
       stack_top=curr; // solution.pop(); solution.push(curr);
    }
    else if(curr.e < stack_top.s) {
      stack_top=curr; // solution.push(curr);
      count++;
    }
  }
  // if you need the solution, arrange the params of the function to return it
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Take a set system where only 2 sets are there. For example, S={{1,3,6},{2,4,8}}. This does not work in these simple cases even.